# ArangoDB Join Edge collections

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, pyarango, python-arango

I have 1 node and two edge collections. I want to write an AQL query to find the common nodes between the two edge collections. How can I join two edge collections as there is not common field in the 2 edge collections to query. As I am trying to find nodes the common node ids can exist either is `_from` or `_to` fields

Let’s say I have 2 edges in 2 different edges collections as the following :
`Edge-1 :  _from: A1 _to: B1 Edge-2 :  _from: B1 _to: C2`

The output would be `B1` because it is common among the two edge collections

Answer (score 0):

following query would return `B1`:

```
FOR e1 IN edge_1
FOR e2 IN edge_2
FILTER e1._to == e2._from
FOR n IN nodes
FILTER n._id == e1._to
RETURN DISTINCT n
```

Comment: what I need is common nodes among the 2 edge collections. Not everything that is referenced in both collections

Comment: sorry, then i did not understand what you mean by "common nodes"

Comment: Please see the updated question about what I mean about common nodes